# Creating an array that contains sorted Counter both by letter and frequency

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, python-3.x

I am learning Python for a few days now and I need help. I am trying to create a program that will ask the user to enter a word/phrase and the program will store it in an array sorted BOTH by letter and frequency.
Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

**Input:** sweet stuff

**Desired output:** `'e':2, 'f':2, 's':2, 't':2, 'u':1, 'w':1, ' ':1`

I have this code, but it only sorts by descending order in terms of the 2nd key (the numbers)

```
arr = []
word = input("Please enter a word/phrase: ")
arr = (collections.Counter(word)).most_common
print (arr)
```

And is there a way to print it vertically? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
for _ in sorted(arr, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):
    print('{}:{}'.format(_[0],_[1]))
```

Explanation: 
The key argument specifies a function (`lambda`) to be called on each list element prior to making comparisons (here, extraction of the 2nd element of each element). This is a common construct in Python.
By setting `reverse=True`, the output starts with the highest element. This equivalent to `sorted(arr, key=lambda x: x[1])[::-1]`.

Take a look [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) for further explanation on how to use `lambda`.